# GCP : Monthly VM Uptime report in percentage

Tags: google-compute-engine

The VMs in our environments are using only internal networks , which consist of both Linux and Windows flavours. Our requirement is to take the monthly report which gives the data of the VM uptime in percentage.

Please suggest if already the solution exists.or suggest steps to get the uptime percentage of the VMs

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom dashboard so you can monitor the uptime of your VM instances.

1. On your Cloud Console menu, click `Dashboards`, then click `+Create dashboard`.
2. Name your dashboard.
3. Click the **Line** option in `Chart library` to add the first chart. Leave the `Chart Title` as default.
4. In the **Resource & Metric** field, search **uptime** (compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime) and click **VM Instance** > **Instance** > **Uptime**. Click **Apply**.

Comment: Hi Marvin, thanks for the reply,but can i get the monthly report in terms of percentage from this dashboard. please help in getting my requirement.